# PHP mySQL multi-level query/report

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database containing:
Actors
Parts
Lines

I would like to be able to query for all Parts and Lines that a particular actor has but I would like to generate the output as:

**Actor One**

**Part One**

- Line One
- Line Two

**Part Two**

- Line Three
- Line Four

Right now Im getting:

**Actor One**

**Part One**

- Line One

**Part One**

- Line Two

**Part Two**

- Line Three

**Part Two**

- Line Four

My query is currently:

```
SELECT * FROM `parts` INNER JOIN actors ON parts.actorid = users.id LEFT JOIN lines ON lines.actorid = parts.id WHERE users.username = :usersearch;
```

Im using

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
```

but somehow I need to do something similar to associate all the "lines" of that "part" under a single listing of that "part"

OK - yes - Im very new at this. I know Im not explaining this well - Im sure this has been answered before but I cant find the right terms to search...

And later I will likely add
**Scenes**
at the same level as lines in the report

I can get this working with one level of "child" records but I need to be able to support two levels deep of "child" records/lists.

---

i have looked at the linked example and I cant see how that works to get me another level deep...

added code as per request

````
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $actorsearch = $_POST["actorsearch"];

    try {
        require_once "includes/dbh.inc.php";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `parts` INNER JOIN actors ON parts.actorid = actors.id LEFT JOIN alines ON parts.id = alines.partid WHERE actors.name = :actorsearch;";
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `parts` INNER JOIN actors ON parts.actorid = actors.id WHERE actors.name = :actorsearch LIMIT 1;";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(":actorsearch", $actorsearch);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt = null;

        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
        $stmt1->bindParam(":actorsearch", $actorsearch);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $results1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt1 = null;
        
print_r($results);

        $pdo = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dw.css">
    <title>Search Results</title>


</head>

<body>

        
        <?php
        
        
        if (empty($results)) {
            echo "<div style='text-align:center'>";
            echo "<p>There were no results!</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        } else {


            foreach ($results1 as $row1) {
                
                echo "<h3>Actor: " . htmlspecialchars($row1["name"]) . "</h3>";
            }

            foreach ($results as $row) {

                echo "<div class='row'><div class='col-6'>";
                
                echo "<table class='charwide'><tr><td><h6>Name:</h6>" . htmlspecialchars($row["name"]) . "</td></tr></table>";
                
                echo "<h7>Parts</h7>";
                echo "<table class='charhalf'><tr><td class='text-align:left'>" . htmlspecialchars($row["pname"]) . "&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";

                echo "<h7>Lines</h7>";
                echo "<table class='charhalf'><tr><td class='text-align:left'>" . htmlspecialchars($row["line"]) . "&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";


                
                echo "</div>";
                

            }
        }

        ?>


</body>

</html>```

Which is giving me:

Actor: Patrick
Name:
Patrick

Parts
Roadhouse 

Lines
Nobody ever wins a fight. 

Name:
Patrick

Parts
Roadhouse 

Lines
I want you to be nice until it's time to not be nice. 

Name:
Patrick

Parts
Dirty Dancing 

Lines
Look, spaghetti arms. This is my dance space. 

Name:
Patrick

Parts
Dirty Dancing 

Lines
And if I leave quietly, I'll get my summer bonus.
````

Comment: You may need to sort and group your results.

Comment: Could you show a more complete version of your PHP code? For instance, what's in your loop.

Comment: I think your answer can be found in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look/comment.  
I added an additional query to return only the lines and the part.id
I ordered the main query by pname 
then within my primary foreach statement I added another foreach that checked if the partsid in the nested row == partsid in the parent row
I still have the actor name repeated with each part so I probably need to add another layer of checking. Is it worth me posting my solution?

Comment: To make your [mcve] clear and attractive to answer, consider including a demo link to phpize.online so that volunteers can instantly trial and confirm there solutions before answering.  I'd prefer to see "Pain don't hurt" in the sample data. ;^) You should only bother to [edit] this question if you are unable to use the advice in the nominated duplicate page.